# Can I create a list inside of an object

Tags: python

I am an intermediate programmer just getting into python.  I am creating a simple classroom manager program that allows you to create a class of students with property names, `age` and `avg`.  I was wondering if it was somehow possible for me to create a function i.e. `getMarks()` that would allow me to insert `x` amount of marks for that student and have that list stored inside the property `avg` (or the `sum(list)/len(list)` for actual average)

here are some code examples so you can understand what I mean better

```
class Student():

    def __init__(self, name, grade, avg):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.avg = avg

    def addStudent():

        studentNum = int(input("How many students do you want to add?: "))

        for n in range(studentNum):

            newName = input("Student Name: ")
            newGrade = int(input("Student Grade: "))
            newAvg = random.randrange(50, 100) 
            # *i would like to be able to store this as a list*
            myClass.append(Student(newName, newGrade, newAvg))
```

here are some things I tried but none of them really worked

```
def setMark():

    markWho = input("Who are you adding a mark(s) for?: ")
    newMark = int(input("Enter mark: "))


    for i in myClass:
        if(i.name == markWho):
            markDict[i] = []

            markDict[i].append(newMark)

def getMark():
    markWho2 = input("Whose mark's would you like to see?: ")

    studAvg = 0

    for i in myClass:
        if(i.name == markWho2):
            studAvg = sum(markDict[i]) / len(markDict[i])
            print(markDict[i] + " \nAccording to this data this student has a {}%       average".format(studAvg))

def getAvg(name):
    for i in markDict:
        if(i.name == name):
        print(markDict[i])
```

Comment: In the `__init__()` definition, add `self.grades = []`. You can append single grades to this list and also extend it with lists of grades, and you can use this attribute to compute averages. If you want, you can keep it private (by prefixing its name with underscores) and create methods to add grades to it, return the list, etc., while keeping it in sync with `avg`. Lists are not problematic attributes in a class definition.

Comment: As an aside, ```addStudent()``` doesn't seem like it should be an attribute of ```Student```.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an attribute markDict in the class Student which is much more easier to manage (since you are dealing with OOP). this attribute will be a list.

Here is an approach

```
import random
myClass=[]
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, grade, avg):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.avg = avg
        #add an attribute for each student class. This attribute is a list
        self.markDict=[]

def addStudent():
    studentNum = int(input("How many students do you want to add?: "))
    for n in range(studentNum):
        newName = input("Student Name: ")
        newGrade = int(input("Student Grade: "))

def setMark():
    markWho = input("Who are you adding a mark(s) for?: ")
    newMark = int(input("Enter mark: "))
    for i in myClass:
        if(i.name == markWho):
            #add this mark to the markDict attribute list for that Student object
            i.markDict.append(newMark)

def getMark():
    markWho2 = input("Whose mark's would you like to see?: ")
    for i in myClass:
        if(i.name == markWho2):

            studAvg = sum(i.markDict) / (len(i.markDict) if len(i.markDict)!=0 else 1)
            print("nAccording to this data this student has a {}%       average".format(studAvg))

def getAvg(name):
    for i in markDict:
        if(i.name == name):
            print(i.markDict)

addStudent()
getMark()
setMark()
getMark()
```

**Here are some outputs**

```
How many students do you want to add?: 2
Student Name: r1
Student Grade: 1
Student Name: r2
Student Grade: 2
Whose mark's would you like to see?: r1
nAccording to this data this student has a 0.0%       average
Who are you adding a mark(s) for?: r1
Enter mark: 25
Whose mark's would you like to see?: r1
nAccording to this data this student has a 25.0%       average
```

Comment: Also I believe you should take out that "%" in your string because this approach simply finds the average of a set of numbers and not relative computation.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
import random 

class Student():

    def __init__(self, name, grade, avg):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.avg = avg
        self.markList = []

    def getAvg(self):
        if len(self.markList) > 0:
            self.avg = sum(self.markList) / len(self.markList)

    def addMark(self,newMarks):
        self.markList.extend(newMarks)

def addStudent():
    studentNum = int(input("How many students do you want to add?: "))
    for n in range(studentNum):
        newName = input("Student Name: ")
        newGrade = int(input("Student Grade: "))
        newAvg = random.randrange(50, 100) 
        myClass.append(Student(newName, newGrade, newAvg))

def setMark():
    markWho = input("Who are you adding a mark(s) for?: ")
    iterMark = int(input("How many marks of student you want to add?:"))
    marks = []
    for i in myClass:
       if (i.name == markWho):
           for item in range(iterMark):
               newMark = int(input("Enter mark: "))
               marks.append(newMark)
           i.addMark(marks)
           i.getAvg()
           break

def getMark():
    markWho2 = input("Whose mark's would you like to see?: ")
    for i in myClass:
        if(i.name == markWho2):
            print(i.markList)
            print(" \nAccording to above data this student has a {}%
    average".format(i.avg))

myClass = []
addStudent()
setMark()
getMark()
```